# Is it possible to administrate screen time on an iPad remotely?

Tags: ipad, screen-time

I want to be able to change the screen time settings on my son's iPad when he or I are travelling. Is that possible? How?

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: @fsb Since I don't know whether what I want is even possible, I don't know what I could possibly have tried. I have tried searching for an answer to my question using Google, and I have tried going through all the settings both on the iPad and in my Apple account. Is that what you mean? Or could it be that your comment doesn't really fit my question?